# Access environment variable on both OSX and Win7

Tags: windows-7, macos, filesystems, environment-variables

I'm fairly sure this is impossible because of syntax issues, but here goes anyway...
I'm using dropbox to sync some files that I need to access in both windows and osx. In the program I need to specify where the files are located so I created the "DROP" environment variable in both windows and osx and pointed it to my dropbox root folder. But windows uses the %% wildcard while osx uses the $ wildcard.

Is there any way I can use this cross-platform or am I going to have to keep reseting them each time I need to use them?

Any way for either os to ignore the wildcards it doesn't recognize?? something like /$DROP%DROP%/.../...

Comment: Which program are you using? How does it access the environment variables?

Comment: I want to attach java docs to jar files in eclipse.. However these are located outside the workspace. The program doesn't have a way to access the variables that I know of.. just adding the path works for either os, but not both

Comment: So are you programming in Java? You can get the OS from Java.